# The scroll always visible when input box is added dynamically in jquery.smartWizard.js in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery.smartWizard.js to display a form(from gantelella template). The form consist of button to dynamically added the textbox, but when click the button the textbox added but the form make it scroll and does not stretch like in the below image. How to make the div dynamically stretch when added new textbox.

[image]

```js
init_SmartWizard();

/* SMART WIZARD */

function init_SmartWizard() {
  if (typeof($.fn.smartWizard) === 'undefined') {
    return;
  }
  console.log('init_SmartWizard');
  $('.custom-wizard').smartWizard({
    buttonOrder: ['prev', 'next']

  });
  $('#wizard_verticle').smartWizard({
    transitionEffect: 'slide'
  });
  $('.buttonNext').addClass('btn btn-success');
  $('.buttonPrevious').addClass('btn btn-primary');
  $('.buttonFinish').addClass('btn btn-default');
};



//jquery function to get the change in company name dropdown
$('#company_name').change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  var quotation_no;
  var company_name;
  //ajax used to get company_name and quotation_no from mysql database
  $.ajax({
    url: "get_company_name.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: ({
      id: id
    }),
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      company_name = data[0];
      quotation_no = data[1];
      // alert(quotation_no);
    }
  });

  //function to take initial character of string
  var str = company_name; //Java Script Object Notation
  var matches = str.match(/\b(\w)/g); // ['J','S','O','N']
  var acronym = matches.join('');

  //function to increase the quotation_no base on previous document.
  //ex if no document exist quotation_no is 001 and if the document exist it will add 1 to latest previous document no
  if (quotation_no == 0) {
    quotation_no = 1;
  } else {
    quotation_no = Number(quotation_no) + 1;
  }

  //function to create quotation id ex Q-(Initial of every company name)-(document no)
  var quotation_id = "Q-" + acronym + "-" + PrependZeros(quotation_no, 3);

  // alert(quotation_id);

  if (!$('#company_name').has('option').length > 0) {
    $("#quo_ref").val("");
  } else {
    $("#quo_ref").val(quotation_id.toUpperCase());
  }


  //
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_purchase_order.php",
    data: ({
      id: id
    }),
    success: function(data) {
      $("#add_po").html(data);
    }
  });


});

//funtion to return 000 for quotation document number ex 001(Q-KSW-001)
var PrependZeros = function(str, len, seperator) {
  if (typeof str === 'number' || Number(str)) {
    str = str.toString();
    return (len - str.length > 0) ? new Array(len + 1 - str.length).join('0') + str : str;
  } else {
    var spl = str.split(seperator || ' ')
    for (var i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
      if (Number(spl[i]) && spl[i].length < len) {
        spl[i] = PrependZeros(spl[i], len)
      }
    }
    return spl.join(seperator || ' ');
  }
};

$('.setFormat').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});

$('#leaveto').datepicker('setDate', 'now');


//Dynamic add table items on step 2

$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $('#add').click(function() {
    i++;


    //Add field document History
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row1' + i + '"><td>1</td>\
             <td style="border:none;">\
                   <input id="item_name" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" name="item_name[]" placeholder="Item Name">\
             </td>\
             <td style="border:none;">\
                     <textarea id="document_description"  class="form-control" name="document_description[]" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-validation-threshold="10" style="height:100px;" placeholder="Business Description"></textarea>\
             </td>\
             <td style="border:none;">\
                   <input id="man_day_rates" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="number" name="man_days_rate[]" placeholder="Man Day Rates">\
             </td>\
             <td style="border:none;">\
                   <input id="estimated_man_days" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="number" name="estimated_man_days[]" placeholder="Estimate Man Days">\
             </td>\
              <td></td>\
              <td style="height: 20px;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;"><a href="#" class="btn_remove">X</a></td>\
              </tr> ');


  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function() {
    var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $('#row0' + button_id + '').remove();
    $('#row1' + button_id + '').remove();
  });

  $("#add").click(function() {
    var height = $("#step-2").height();
    height = height + 1000;
    $("#wizard").css("height", height);
  });

});
```

```css
.form_wizard .stepContainer {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 solid #CCC;
  overflow-x: hidden
}

.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps {
  display: table;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 20px
}

.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center
}

.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps li a,
.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps li:hover {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  color: #666
}

.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 0
}

.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps li a.disabled .step_no {
  background: #ccc
}

.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps li a .step_no {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5
}

.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps li a.selected:before,
.step_no {
  background: #34495E;
  color: #fff
}

.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps li a.done:before,
.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps li a.done .step_no {
  background: #1ABB9C;
  color: #fff
}

.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps li:first-child a:before {
  left: 50%
}

.wizard_horizontal ul.wizard_steps li:last-child a:before {
  right: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  left: auto
}

.wizard_verticle .stepContainer {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px
}

.actionBar {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-top: 10px
}

.actionBar .buttonDisabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: .65;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  box-shadow: none
}

.actionBar a {
  margin: 0 3px
}

.wizard_verticle .wizard_content {
  width: 80%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps {
  display: table;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 20px
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li {
  display: list-item;
  text-align: center
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li a {
  height: 80px
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li a:first-child {
  margin-top: 20px
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li a,
.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li:hover {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
  color: #666
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  top: 20px;
  width: 4px;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 49%
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li a.disabled .step_no {
  background: #ccc
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li a .step_no {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li a.selected:before,
.step_no {
  background: #34495E;
  color: #fff
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li a.done:before,
.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li a.done .step_no {
  background: #1ABB9C;
  color: #fff
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li:first-child a:before {
  left: 49%
}

.wizard_verticle ul.wizard_steps li:last-child a:before {
  left: 49%;
  left: auto;
  width: 0
}

.form_wizard .loader {
  display: none
}

.form_wizard .msgBox {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Smart Wizard -->

<div id="wizard" class="form_wizard wizard_horizontal custom-wizard" style="100%;">
  <ul class="wizard_steps" style="padding:0px;">
    <li>
      <a href="#step-1">
        <span class="step_no">1</span>
        <span class="step_descr">
                                                        Step 1<br />
                                                        <small>Quotation Details</small>
                                                    </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#step-2">
        <span class="step_no">2</span>
        <span class="step_descr">
                                                        Step 2<br />
                                                        <small>Quotation Items</small>
                                                    </span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#step-3">
        <span class="step_no">3</span>
        <span class="step_descr">
                                                        Step 3<br />
                                                        <small>Quotation Preview</small>
                                                    </span>
      </a>
    </li>

  </ul>


  <?php

                                     $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY company_name asc");
                                     $stmt->execute();

                                ?>

    <div id="step-1">

      <br>
      <h2 class="StepTitle" style="text-align: center;">Step 1 Quotation Details</h2>
      <hr>
      <br>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="quo_ref">Company Name <span class="required">*</span>
                                            </label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <select class="form-control" id="company_name" name="company_name" required="required">
            <option value="">(Choose Company)</option>
            <?php
                                                               while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                                                               {
                                                                       echo '<option value="'.$row['cust_id'].'">'.ucwords(strtolower($row['company_name'])).'</option>';
                                                               }

                                                            ?>


          </select>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="quo_ref">Quotation Reference No<span class="required">*</span>
                                            </label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" id="quo_ref" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="quo_ref">Quotation Title <span class="required">*</span>
                                            </label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" id="quo_title" name="quo_title" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="">
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="middle-name" class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Quotation Date <span class="required">*</span></label>

        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div id="datepicker-custom" class="input-group date setFormat" data-provide="datepicker" style="margin:0px;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control setFormat" name="leaveto" id="leaveto" data-rel="datepicker" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
              <i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-addon" style="margin-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
              <a href="#" class="clear1" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;padding-right: 10px;padding-left: 10px">Clear</a>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="quo_ref">Choose Purchase Order <span class="required">*</span>
                                            </label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <select class="form-control" id="add_po" name="add_po" required="required">
            <option value="">(Please Select Company Name)</option>

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>




    </div>

    <div id="step-2">
      <br>
      <h2 class="StepTitle" style="text-align: center;">Step 2 Quotation Items</h2>
      <hr>
      <br>

      <table class="table table-striped" id="dynamic_field">
        <thead>
          <tr class="headings">
            <th class="column-title">#</th>
            <th class="column-title">Item Name</th>
            <th class="column-title">Description </th>
            <th class="column-title" style="width:100px;">Man Day Rates (RM)</th>
            <th class="column-title" style="width:100px;">Estimated Man Days </th>
            <th class="column-title" style="width:100px;">Subtotal (RM)</th>
            <th class="column-title" style="width:100px;"></th>
            </th>

          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <tr>

            <td>1</td>
            <td style="border:none;">
              <input id="item_name" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="text" name="item_name[]" placeholder="Item Name">
            </td>
            <td style="border:none;">
              <textarea id="document_description" class="form-control" name="document_description[]" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" data-parsley-validation-threshold="10" style="height:100px;" placeholder="Business Description"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td style="border:none;">
              <input id="man_day_rates" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="number" name="man_days_rate[]" placeholder="Man Day Rates">
            </td>
            <td style="border:none;">
              <input id="estimated_man_days" class="form-control  col-md-7 col-xs-12" type="number" name="estimated_man_days[]" placeholder="Estimate Man Days">
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;line-height: 20px;white-space: nowrap;"><a href="#" class="btn_remove">X</a></td>

            <td></td>

          </tr>


        </tbody>
      </table>

      <button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Items</button>

    </div>


    <div id="step-3">

      <br>
      <h2 class="StepTitle" style="text-align: center;">Step 3 Bill Address</h2>
      <hr>
      <br>

      <div class="form-group">

        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="address">Address <span class="required">*</span>
                                            </label>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <input type="text" id="address" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="city">Country <span class="required">*</span>
                                            </label>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <select class="form-control ddlCustomerCountry" id="ddlCountry" required="required">

          </select>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="state">State <span class="required">*</span>
                                            </label>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <select class="form-control ddlCustomerState" required="required" id="ddlState">

          </select>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="city">City <span class="required">*</span>
                                            </label>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <select class="form-control" id="city" required="required">
            <option value="0">Choose option</option>
            <option>Option one</option>
            <option>Option two</option>
            <option>Option three</option>
            <option>Option four</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="zip">Zip <span class="required">*</span>
                                            </label>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <select class="form-control" id="zip" required="required">
            <option value="0">Choose option</option>
            <option>Option one</option>
            <option>Option two</option>
            <option>Option three</option>
            <option>Option four</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>



</div>
<!-- End SmartWizard Content -->
</form>
```